# TypeError: argmax(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not str

Tags: bert-language-model, nlp-question-answering

My code was working fine and when I tried to run it today without changing anything I got the following error:
TypeError: argmax(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not str

Would appreciate if help could be provided.

below is the code snippet where I am getting an error. I am using BERT mdoel

start_scores, end_scores = model(torch.tensor([input_ids]),  # The tokens representing our input text.
token_type_ids=torch.tensor(
[segment_ids]))  # The segment IDs to differentiate question from answer_text

```
# ======== Reconstruct Answer ========
# Find the tokens with the highest `start` and `end` scores.

answer_start = torch.argmax(start_scores)
answer_end = torch.argmax(end_scores)
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? Because I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your line of code

`start_scores, end_scores = model(torch.tensor([input_ids]),token_type_ids=torch.tensor([segment_ids]))`

you have to make it:

`start_scores, end_scores = model(torch.tensor([input_ids]),token_type_ids=torch.tensor([segment_ids]), return_dict=False)`.

It worked for me. I had the same problem.